# R: Shortening strings

Tags: regex, r, string

What would be the best way to abbreviate an example string `ANNNNNNTCCGGG` into `AN6TCCG3` so that it counts all characters that repeat more than 2 times, and expresses them in numbers?

Comment: Have you searched for an R package for DNA math which might come with such a function?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I've tried looking for a specific R package that does this, but couldn't find one so far. It might be that I'm searching with the wrong terms...

Comment: Does it have to be *more* than 2? What if there is a solution that would easily turn something like AAABBC into A3B2C?

Comment: If there was an easy way to do that, that would be great as well!

Comment: You should take a look at Bioconductor. `IRanges` & `Biostrings` may have useful things for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is probably a faster way but using base R

```
r <- rle(unlist(strsplit("ANNNNNNTCCGGG", ""))) # Compute RLE
m <- rbind(r$values, r$lengths) # Combine
paste(ifelse(m == 1, "", m), collapse="")
```

Answer (score 3):

I suspect there is probably a package in bioconductor that will do what you want but it isn't too hard to throw something together in base R

```
rle_shortener <- function(strings){
    cvecs <- strsplit(strings, "")
    sapply(cvecs, function(input){
        # Get the run length encoding of the input
        r <- rle(input)
        lens <- r$lengths
        # replace the 1s with blanks so that they
        # don't show up in the resulting string
        lens[lens == 1] <- ""
        # paste the character with the lengths
        paste(r$values, lens, collapse = "", sep = "")
    })
}


> rle_shortener(c("heeeeyo", "ANNNNNNTCCGGG"))
[1] "he4yo"    "AN6TC2G3"
```

Answer (score 3):

If "performance/speed" is not an issue, here is another approach:

```
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn('(.)\\1{2,}', ~ paste0(x, nchar(`&`)), 'ANNNNNNTCCGGG')
# [1] "AN6TCCG3"
```